# Sharing a private URL in google plus

Tags: google-plus

I am trying to use `https://plus.google.com/share?url=<URL>` to programmatically share a site to a private circle on Google Plus.  It's not a problem when I use an externally visible website, but I would like to share a private URL (host on an internal network).

When I use a private URL, the plus sharing page shows a spinning icon, as though it's trying to access the internal URL for content, and the 'share' button remains dim - I cannot move forward.

I tried adding noverify=true or verify=false, etc to the GET line, but that didn't change the behavior. I suspect it can be done, because I can post private URLs via the taberareloo plugin on chrome.

Is there a way to skip probing the provided URL link, or otherwise post a private URL when posting to Google plus circles using the `https://plus.google.com/share?url=<URL>` mechanism?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no way to skip the fetch of the target page when you use the share link.

The fetch is how the [snippet](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/snippet/) of your page, that is shared to Google+, is created. Without this fetch there would not actually be anything to share.

Comment: Sure there is: I want to share the link, and my own description, I don't need it parsed by Google.

Comment: The share link does not support this use case. It can only share public pages.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the answer (for now)

Comment: You can easily post private links as an activity with simple text and the link sent as text. G+ will display the text with a clickable link.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a funky workaround, but you could have a public page which is just a redirector (not a  301, but rather a javascript or meta redirect), and provide that link to G+. It would understand it to be a normal public page, while the user experience would be to get redirected to your internal link.